# How can I retrieve an Excel IRibbonUI instance in Python using win32com?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, win32com, pyxll

I'm trying to invalidate specific controls on an Excel add-in ribbon using Python's `win32com` package in order to have their callbacks re-fire.

Reading over Microsoft's [Object References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/library-reference/reference-object-library-reference-for-office) and the [IRibbonUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui) documentation all I've seen recommended is to save a reference to the ribbon in its `onLoad` callback. This is also how I've accomplished this in the past when coding in VBA. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to get to that point using python's `win32com` package.

I'm using [PyXLL](https://www.pyxll.com/) as a means to code the add-in using Python and for future distribution as an xll instead of xlam. By using this I'm able to access the ribbon com object in the ribbon `onLoad` callback, but not within the `onClick` callbacks of the controls included in the ribbon, since the only parameter passed into those functions is the control's com object.

## Some relavent debugging info

- parameter passed into the ribbon `onLoad` callback is an instance of `win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library.IRibbonUI`
- the parameter's `_oleobj_` value is a `PyIDispatch` instance
- The errors seems to center around the `DispatchBaseClass` in `win32com.client`

```py
class DispatchBaseClass:
    def __init__(self, oobj=None):
        if oobj is None:
            oobj = pythoncom.new(self.CLSID)
        elif isinstance(oobj, DispatchBaseClass):
            try:
                oobj = oobj._oleobj_.QueryInterface(
                    self.CLSID, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch
                )  # Must be a valid COM instance
            except pythoncom.com_error as details:
                import winerror

                # Some stupid objects fail here, even tho it is _already_ IDispatch!!??
                # Eg, Lotus notes.
                # So just let it use the existing object if E_NOINTERFACE
                if details.hresult != winerror.E_NOINTERFACE:
                    raise
                oobj = oobj._oleobj_
        self.__dict__["_oleobj_"] = oobj  # so we dont call __setattr__
```

- My thinking is to save a reference to the actual class, recreate it, set the `CLSID` class variable, then instantiate the new class.

```py
def ribbon_loaded(ribbon):
    r_class = ribbon.__class__

    # was thinking I could pickle this class for use elsewhere
    class RibbonUI(r_class):  # also tried type(r_class)
        CLSID = ribbon.CLSID
    
    # just checking below that this would work

    # if CLSID is not set on the new class above __init__ fails
    # but, even when provided __new__ fails with the next line
    new_ribbon = RibbonUI()

    new_ribbon.InvalidateControl("ribbon_control_1")
```

Without setting `CLSID` on the new class the error is

```
2022-07-06 20:48:09,294 - INFO : ribbon.CLSID: IID('{000C03A7-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}')
2022-07-06 20:48:09,314 - ERROR : Error calling ribbon function 'components.ribbon.ribbon_loaded'
2022-07-06 20:48:15,364 - ERROR : Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-07-06 20:48:15,364 - ERROR :   File "C:\Users\mhill\PycharmProjects\excel-addin\components\ribbon.py", line 46, in ribbon_loaded
2022-07-06 20:48:15,365 - ERROR :     new_ribbon = RibbonUI()
2022-07-06 20:48:15,366 - ERROR :   File "c:\users\mhill\PyCharmProjects\excel-addin\.venv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 514, in __init__
2022-07-06 20:48:15,366 - ERROR :     oobj = pythoncom.new(self.CLSID)
2022-07-06 20:48:15,366 - ERROR : pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', None, None)
```

When creating the new class and specifying the the `CLSID` class variable the error becomes

```
2022-07-06 20:48:22,429 - INFO : ribbon.CLSID: IID('{000C03A7-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}')
2022-07-06 20:48:22,429 - ERROR : Error calling ribbon function 'components.ribbon.ribbon_loaded'
2022-07-06 20:48:28,949 - ERROR : Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-07-06 20:48:28,950 - ERROR :   File "C:\Users\mhill\PycharmProjects\excel-addin\components\ribbon.py", line 46, in ribbon_loaded
2022-07-06 20:48:28,951 - ERROR :     new_ribbon = RibbonUI()
2022-07-06 20:48:28,951 - ERROR : TypeError: type.__new__() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40388958/2962937) mentions something about creating an IDTExtensibility2 object, but not quite sure what to do with that.

## The question

Apart from mimicking saving a global reference to the ribbon object from within the ribbon's `onLoad` callback as Microsoft's documentation suggests, how can I properly save a reference to the IRibbonUI com object when in the ribbon onLoad callback and be able to access it in the controls' `onClick` callbacks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh, looks like the global variable option is [the recommended route](https://support.pyxll.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360042867554-How-can-I-update-ribbon-controls-)

## Excerpt

> ...
> For example, in your ribbon XML you would add the onLoad action to the
> customUI element as follows (assuming your code is in a module named
> your_module.py):
>
> ```xml
> <customUI
>  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"
>  onLoad="your_module.on_load"
> >
>  <!-- your ribbon definition here -->
> </customUI>
> ```
>
> Then in your module ("your_module.py" is used above) you would add the action
> function "on_load" that takes the IRibbonUI object. You can then save
> it as a global variable so that you can call the "Invalidate" method
> later.
>
> ```py
> _ribbon = None
>
> def on_load(control):
>     global _ribbon
>     _ribbon = control
>
> # Later when you want to invalidate a control you would call
> _ribbon.InvalidateControl(control_id)
> ```